# bootstrap-combined.min.css -- how can two tabs (in different tab controls) each have a class=active and have different background-colors ?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand css logic -- and a Bootstrap Tab Control sample project at jsfiddle is using bootstrap-combined.min.css which contains several  .active listings.  Here is a sample of the project code that is confusing me:

```
    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        ......
      </ul>
    </div>

    ...

    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
    .......
    </ul>
```

Both Home and Regular link are referenced by class=active and href="#".  Obviuosly these are different .active classes.  I am thinking that each tab is under a different super css class and that is how the different class=active are distinguished, but I am not sure about that because the background-color for each tab does not appear to be located with a respective .active.   How do these tabs both have class=active but have different background colors?

here is the demo project at jsfiddle

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/3100/)

The reason I want to know is (not just that I want to understand css better) because I want to modify these background-colors and should I modify bootstrap-combined.min.css or should I just create another css file and reference a different .active class there? or just add some css inside my project?

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for? You can always inspect the element in a browser and look at what classes are being used. Mark as answer below if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Background color of 'Regular Link' is coming from `.nav-pills>.active>a` Whereas the background color of 'Home' is coming from `.navbar .nav>.active>a`

Since, they are different, the colors are different and you can override them easily.

Never make changes in original bootstrap css file. You should override classes only on components you want to have different styles.